# MyFirebaseInstanceIDService get has no default constructor

Tags: android, firebase

So, i have this class. This class will save the `device token` to shared preference.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    Context myCon;

    public MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(Context mCon){
        this.myCon=mCon;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        storeToken(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void storeToken(String token) {
        SessionHandler.getInstance(myCon).saveDeviceId(token);
    }
}
```

and here is how i use that class from other activity

```
MyFirebaseInstanceIDService firebaseService = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(Login_activity.this);
firebaseService.onTokenRefresh();
```

and here is my manifest

```
<service
   android:name=".custom_services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

So, in my manifest above i get this message

> MyFirebaseInstanceIDService has no default constructor

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call service object directly. Android will handle your service once your declare it inside manifest file.

You also don't need to add a constructor to pass context, since service will have context available inside it.

If you need to refresh token forcefully do this (it will throw error is run on main thread so use a aync task or use other thread) :

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Once the token is refreshed the method `public void onTokenRefresh()` will get called and your functionality inside will run.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` :

```
public MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define constructor. Your class should simply be like

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        Log.d("mDeviceToken", token);

    }
}
```

There is no need of

```
  MyFirebaseInstanceIDService firebaseService = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(Login_activity.this);
    firebaseService.onTokenRefresh();
```

You just need to save your token(may be in sharedPreference) in OnTokenRefresh().

Answer (score 0):

No need to call MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class

You can get `Device Token` from any Activity calling...

```
String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Clas Architecture .

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIdService extends Service
```

i.e `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is a `Service` So you do not have to pass `Context` to it cause it has its own `Context` So you do not have to have a parameterized constructor.

And If you do not have any constructor a default Constructor is injected by the compiler automatically . That's it . Just keep it Simple .

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Log.d("mDeviceToken", token);

}
}
```